# Can't delete file in download folder

Tags: internal-storage, samsung, downloading

A few days ago, I downloaded a file of 1.9gb to my phone using the utorrent app. Utorrent downloaded the file automatically to my internal storage, and since I only had 2 gigs of free space, the download did stop after a while. when I saw it I deleted some files, and the download went on. When the download was finished, I decided to take a look in my folder but the folder which *did* have the name of the file that I downloaded was empty. So I checked my internal storage, but it was almost full, so the file must be somewhere on my device.

Furthermore can't I delete that empty folder. By the way: my phone (Samsung Galaxy S4) is not rooted.

How can I find that file, and how can I delete that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone especially you geffcheng! I finally found a way to delete the file. I thought that it might work if I downloaded the same file on my pc, and then transfered it to the same folder(downloads) on the internal storage on my phone. I thought that my pc would ask if I wanted to overwrite the existing folder, but my pc didn't and I had 2 exactly the same folders in my download folder. Then I turned on the SDmaid app on my phone(while it was still plugged in my pc), and I deleated the whole download folder. It actually worked!!

So thanks again to everyone who helped!

P.S. I'm sorry if you could't understand everything. I'm Dutch;)

Answer (score 2):

You could try [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm&hl=en), and see if it can find the file. It has a feature that lets you search for the BIGGEST files. If that file was cached somewhere before it was put into the correct folder, chances are SD Maid might be able to find it.

I can't remember though if you need the Pro version to use the feature, but do check it out.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I found the folder with the files within, but I am unable to delete the folder, and I can't see the files when I open the folder. When I try to delete the folder, the app says that my phone is in need of root acces. That's quite strage since my phone has never been rooted. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @user47066 It means you need to be rooted to delete that folder / file. This is understandable, since it is most likely a temporary file. Have you tried deleting the torrent and data from utorrent itself?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but it didn't work either. I even downloaded the same torrent again, and the torrent started checking the file. when the check was complete Utorrent showed the following error: Invalid download state, try resuming.

Comment: @zwadde03 What happens if you resume it?

Comment: @zwadde03 How did you solve the problem? Is it using my answer? If yes, please upvote and accept my answer. If it's using your own solution, please post a separate answer and accept it in 2 days. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using File Manager (Rhythm Software) to find and delete it.

Comment: As the user's already found the file, but can't delete it without root, how would using a different file manager help?

Comment: Same problem as before: I can find the map, but I am unable to edit the map in any way

Answer (score 0):

Go into to your settings on android. Then to storage, then wait for it to load phone file. Then tap on it. Then, used space, then, select audio or whatever file you are looking for, but for this question select audio...You will then see different folders there. Tap on each until you find what you are looking for. Press and hold one file then from there to delete more files after holding down one file the trash can comes up then you can select each folder from there then tap trash can. All done